# Prestashop error that doesn't show all the product images

Tags: prestashop, e-commerce

I uploaded several pictures for each product, but when I preview the product page there is shown only the main image[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8t7n.png)

I'm using the warehouse theme, and haven't installed any external module.

I've checked that all the images were uploaded correctly,

Not sure if the warehouse theme shows multiple images by default, so please, any help will come in handy

[configuration check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6lsi.png)